# problem continuing a table

Tags: tables

I'm trying to build a table where there are explained physical formulas inside, my intention is to create two tables where one is the topic and the second is the explanation. The problem is that in anticipation of very large lines I can't make it continue on the next page just like Word does because it truncates the content. This is the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {Long Title},
        label = {tab:test},
        ]{
            colspec = {|X|X|}, % Utilizza colonne X con larghezza automatica
            rowhead = 1,
            hlines,
            row{even} = {gray9},
            row{1} = {olive9},
        } 
        topic explained & formula explained \\
        topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1 topic1   & formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 formula1 \\
        topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2 topic2   & formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2 formula2  \\
        foo  & bar \\
        foo  & bar \\
        foo  & bar \\
        foo  & bar \\
        foo  & bar \\
        foo  & bar \\
        foo  & bar \\
        f & bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar barbar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar barbar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar barbar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar barbar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar barbar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar barbar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar barbar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar barbar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar \\ % Imposta l'altezza massima per le celle con la stessa etichetta "myrow"
        foo  & bar \\
        foo  & bar \\
    \end{longtblr}
    
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Have a look at longtable, e.g. by searching here first, e.g. via tags: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/longtable , which you can refine like https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Blongtable%5D+page+break .

Comment: @MS-SPO OP is already using `longtblr`, but the problem is, that there is too much text within a single cell. The automatic page breaks will only be inserted between cells.

Comment: If a single cell is larger than a page, a table might not be the best representation form for this, as there is also much empty / unused space on the left.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Table_across_several_pages) is a wiki page to create tables across several pages. They recommend various environments.

Comment: @Dexteritas How should i do? or do you have any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: As I said, the automatic page breaks work only between the cells. So you can either divide your cells, so they are smaller (and better breakable), or don't use a table but e.g. normal text with headings.

Comment: @Dexteritas I had thought about using the columns but apparently the columns cannot be customizable